# How to remove a user completely from a SharePoint 2013 site collection?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions

When i tried to remove a user completely from a site collection(Went to Site Groups--> groupId=0 and removed the user), the user got deleted from all the groups but he is still possessing permissions somewhere.

Any Ideas..?!!

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Go to `http://siteUrl/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`. From here, you can delete a user from the Site Collection.

It should be noted that the user will remain in the User Information List (`dbo.UserInfo`) table in the Content Database the Site Collection resides in. This is for referential integrity purposes. They are simply marked as deleted.

Comment: Could it be possible that some users won't appear in this list either? (E.g.: I have the same user twice (same `DisplayName`, but different `UserLogin`), and I can see there's 2 using powershell `$web.AllUsers`, but in the SharePoint page, I see only the good one.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try using the below powershell

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Get the Root web
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/operations"
#Supply the user account
$UserAccount = "Global\DaveP"
#Removes user from site collection
Remove-SPUser -Identity $UserAccount -Web $Web -Confirm:$False
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/delete-users-from-site-collection-using-powershell.html#ixzz3zshUIaQT

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the user is a site admin for this collection. You can check it in Center Administration or (if do not have access to central administration) with this simple code in csom.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://mysitecollection"))
{
    var user = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser("user1");
    clientContext.Load(user);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("IsSiteAdmin: {0}", user.IsSiteAdmin);
}
```

PS. Another option - grant Full Control for user in Wep Appliction\User Policy (you need to have access to Central Administration).